# Laravel 5.8 Session Miss From API Callback

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5.8

I want use Session to save value in Laravel, But I lost the session data. How do I do?

I tried change `.env` SESSION_DRIVER to 'redis' or 'file', but it still not working.

This is My Api Callback function, I save session in here.

**A file.php**

```
public function getAccount(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $request->session()->forget('account');
            $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

            Log::info('result => '.($data['result'][0]));

            if($data['error']) {
                Log::info('CoolWalletController GetAccount Has Error : ' . $data['result']);
            }else{

                $request->session()->put('account', $data['result'][0]);

            }

            $request->session()->save();

            Log::info('Session => '.session('account'));

            Log::info('====================');

            return 'ok';
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Log::info('FAILED!!');
        }
    }
```

This is my Log file :

```
[2019-05-16 17:20:40] local.INFO: ====================  
[2019-05-16 17:20:58] local.INFO: result => 0xb74bCB9747dBd6DfC75D1E9321e75766705cf213  
[2019-05-16 17:20:58] local.INFO: Session => 0xb74bCB9747dBd6DfC75D1E9321e75766705cf213  
[2019-05-16 17:20:58] local.INFO: ====================  
[2019-05-16 17:34:52] local.INFO: result => 0xb74bCB9747dBd6DfC75D1E9321e75766705cf213  
[2019-05-16 17:34:52] local.INFO: Session => 0xb74bCB9747dBd6DfC75D1E9321e75766705cf213  
[2019-05-16 17:34:52] local.INFO: ====================  
[2019-05-16 17:37:21] local.INFO: result => 0xb74bCB9747dBd6DfC75D1E9321e75766705cf213  
[2019-05-16 17:37:21] local.INFO: Session => 0xb74bCB9747dBd6DfC75D1E9321e75766705cf213  
[2019-05-16 17:37:21] local.INFO: ====================  
[2019-05-16 17:47:43] local.INFO: result => 0xb74bCB9747dBd6DfC75D1E9321e75766705cf213  
[2019-05-16 17:47:43] local.INFO: Session => 0xb74bCB9747dBd6DfC75D1E9321e75766705cf213  
[2019-05-16 17:47:43] local.INFO: ====================
```

This is another controller function that I want to get Session here.
**B file.php**

```
public function phone(Request $request)
    {

        $account =  $request->session()->get('account', null);

        return view('user.trade.phone', compact('account'));
    }
```

I always get $account is Null.

The session just in **A file.php** has save. But **B file.php** always can not get.

---

@Rezrazi :

dd($request->session()->all()):

```
array:4 [▼
  "_previous" => array:1 [▶]
  "_flash" => array:2 [▶]
  "_token" => "zFuqDPebryzAF03ALGb31JIqxG2JxOUlKtSvqPWd"
]
```

(I also wonder session 'account' where is it)

php artisan route:list (a part of all)

```
|        | POST          | api/coolWallet/getAccount       | api.coolWallet.getAccount       | App\Http\Controllers\Api\CoolWalletController@getAccount       | web
```

Comment: Which middleware group are you using ? `api` or `web`
If you have defined your routes in `api.php` then you wont be able to use sessions as it not loaded

Comment: ```Route::prefix('api')->group(function () {

    Route::post('coolWallet/getAccount', 'Api\CoolWalletController@getAccount')->name('api.coolWallet.getAccount');

});
```

api does not use middleware

Comment: Have you defined this route in `routes/api.php` ?

Comment: Haven't.
I define the route at 

``` routes/web.php```

Comment: Could you `dd($request->session()->all())` to get a dump of all your loaded sessions, and could you post your `php artisan route:list`

Comment: Could you please edit your post and update it with the dumps, makes it easier to read

Comment: Ok, I updated it!

Comment: how you requesting your route? session mechanics based on laravel_session cookie, so you should pass this cookie with request to make it works

Comment: This route is not required just for api callback.
And i found the problem! I didn't save because I didn't go through the browser.
So I changed the method, using redis to save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Session** needs browser support.
So the api route not return back to browser, it is just for callback .

so I using `Redis::set('key','value');` instead of session.

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this:**

```
$account =  $request->session()->get('account');
```

**Routes structure:**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web'], 'prefix' => 'api'], function(){

   // YOUR ROUTES
});
```

**Function A**

```
public function getAccount(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $request->session()->put('account', "TEST");
            return 'ok';
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Log::info('FAILED!!');
        }
    }
```

**Function B**

```
public function phone(Request $request)
    {
        $account =  $request->session()->get('account');
        // Check the value
        dd($account);
        return view('user.trade.phone', compact('account'));
    }
```

Comment: I have already tried it, it is invalid.
I think problem is not in here.

Comment: Post your routes please

Comment: ```
Route::prefix('api')->group(function () {

    Route::post('coolWallet/getAccount', 'Api\CoolWalletController@getAccount')->name('api.coolWallet.getAccount');

});
```

Comment: use my routes group suggest structure please

Comment: Sorry, but the result is the same as before.

Comment: Let me know what return my TEST suggest

Comment: sorry , the result will be the same before.
dd($account); -> null